# Как отобразить комментарий под статьёй, под которой его написали, через PDO PHP?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

У меня есть две таблицы: `articles(id, title, slug, content, author_id, date)` и `comments(id, author_id, article_id, content, date)`. Я хочу отображать комментарии под постом, под которым его задали, то есть сравнивать, соответствует ли `id` из таблицы `articles` с `article_id` из таблицы comments. Это самописный блог, никаких шаблонизаторов или паттернов, использую `PDO PHP`. 
Примерно делаю следующее:

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM articles');   
$comments = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM comments WHERE article_id = ?');
```

Дальше не совсем понятно, что делать. Как поступить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/*
запрос вида index.php?post_id=...
*/
// Получаем пост по его id
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = ?');
$stmt->execute([$_GET['post_id']]);
$postData = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

/*
ИЛИ запрос вида index.php?post_slug=first-article
*/
// Получаем пост по его slug
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE slug = ?');
$stmt->execute([$_GET['post_slug']]);
$postData = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(empty($postData)){
    die('Article not found!');
}

// Получаем все коментарии к данному посту
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM comments WHERE article_id = ?');
$stmt->execute([$postData['id']]);
$commentsData = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Или я не правильно понял суть вопроса...

Comment: Спасибо. У меня в GET параметре передаётся slug статьи, то есть "index.php?first-article". Лучше уж тогда поменять на id, получается?

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: "index.php?first-article" - здесь идет только передача параметра без его значения. Правильно: "index.php?slug=first-article"

Comment: А лучше, если будут не только посты, давать имя параметров по человечески. Например, "index.php?post=first-article". И для лучшей наглядности, посмотреть в сторону [ЧПУ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_URL)

Comment: Вы правы, но это абсолютно самописный блог для собственного развития, про ЧПУ знаю. Возможно, сейчас попробую сделать так. Спасибо ещё раз.

Comment: $stmt->execute([$postData[0]['id']]); -- в этой строке выдаёт ошибку вида Illegal string offset 'id' in...

Comment: @neliudov, обновил

Comment: Большое спасибо, работает.

Comment: @neliudov, отметьте ответ